# Trying to flip the position of the OK and Cancel buttons inside an Antd modal using okButtonProps and cancelButtonProps for button position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I'm using Antd's Modal component for a project and I'm attempting to customize it.

I need to flip the position of the `ok` and `cancel` buttons so that the `ok` button is on the left and the `cancel` is on the right.

I'm also attempting to change the icon color to red.

I looked into the [PR](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/11622) that someone just put in for the Antd project to add this required functionality, but I can't anything that actually describes what prop I need to use in order to change the positioning.

I have a CodeSandbox below with my progress thus far

[image: Edit nifty-khorana-frw23]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Modal, Button } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import "./styles.css";

function showConfirm() {
  Modal.confirm({
    title: "Do you Want to delete these items?",
    content: "Some descriptions",
    iconType: "close-circle",
    okButtonProps: {},
    cancelButtonProps: {},
    onOk() {
      console.log("OK");
    },
    onCancel() {
      console.log("Cancel");
    }
  });
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Modal</h1>
      <Button onClick={showConfirm}>Click For Modal</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Modal.method()`](https://ant.design/components/modal/#Modal.method()) is pretty limited, so I would build custom modal [using `footer` property](https://codesandbox.io/s/43r46m6y24).

Anyway, you can just flip the buttons or edit the CSS class like [@Rikin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381358/7882470):

```js
function showConfirm() {
  Modal.confirm({
    title: 'Do you Want to delete these items?',
    content: 'Some descriptions',
    iconType: 'close-circle',
    okText: 'Cancel',
    cancelText: 'OK',
    okButtonProps: {
      type: 'default'
    },
    cancelButtonProps: {
      type: 'primary'
    },
    onOk() {
      console.log('Cancel');
    },
    onCancel() {
      console.log('OK');
    }
  });
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57379945-FlipModalButtons]

Answer (score 5):

Although PR is mentioned when I go look at the codebase, and PR there dont seem to be any option that does what it needs to. Probably author of the PR did not understand the requirement. You can mention on the comment as unresolved so that they reopen.

Until then possible solution that you can implement:

Edited snippet solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-wave-p69yt

There's `className` property which is available as a prop that you can pass in to Modal, dont see any option to directly affecting position in of the buttons within the Modal.

I added this property in the component

```
className: "my-custom-class",
```

And added following CSS rule in styles.css:

```
.my-custom-class .ant-modal-confirm-btns .ant-btn{
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

You can optimize however you want. This is just one-way to tackle using CSS affecting the modal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **change the icon color to red** then the following answer will help ..........
Modal.confirm will always have yellow color. In order to change the color into red you need to pass the color as red for the icon property. Please refer the below code.

```
import { CloseCircleFilled } from '@ant-design/icons';
...
...
 Modal.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm Title',
    content: 'ABC.....',
    okText:'OK',  
    icon: <CloseCircleFilled style={{ color: '#ff2a00' }} />,
    onOk: () => {
      // code to be implemented
    },
  });
```

The above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If supplement the above, then you can use this option:

```
className: 'custom-confirm-styles',
```

Add next styles

```
 .custom-confirm-styles > .ant-modal-content > .ant-modal-body > .ant-modal-confirm-body-wrapper > .ant-modal-confirm-btns {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      column-gap: 8px;
    }
```

it will look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo7t6.png)